# how to pass the argument, when dynamically decoding a base64 encoded shell script, and executing

Tags: linux, shell, unix, base64, pipe

I have a script

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script is executed"
echo "Input argument for this script is $1"
password="xyz"
```

If I execute the script, I am getting

> ./test.sh hello
>
> Script is executed  
> Input argument for this script is hello

As I have the password in the script, I decided to encode it with base64

base64 test.sh > o

To execute the script, I am using (decoding the obfuscated output to input and executing)

> base64 -d o | sh
>
> output is
>
> Script is executed 
> Input argument for this script is

My question is, how can I pass the "hello" argument to this execution method "base64 -d o | sh"

if I try this, I am getting

> $ base64 -d o | sh hello 
> sh: hello: No such file or directory

Note: I cannot pass the argument from a file, as it is keyyed-in by the user dynamically.

Comment: Can you use a temporary file?  base64 -d o > tmp.file && sh tmp.file hello && rm tmp.file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
base64 -d o | sh -s hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`base64 -d o | sh -s hello`